# Closures resolving strategy not working in trait context in Groovy 2.4.3

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, grails-2.5

I've got the following code:

```
 trait ContainingClosure {

  def method() {
      def delegateClass = new DelegateClass()

      def closure = {
          methodFromDelegate()
      }

      closure.delegate = delegateClass
      closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

      closure.call()
  }

}

class DelegateClass {
    def methodFromDelegate() {
      println 'methodFromDelegate called'
    }
}

class Main implements ContainingClosure {}
new Main().method()
```

The problem is that `methodFromDelegate()` cannot be found when I run `call()` method and the following exception is thrown:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Main.methodFromDelegate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Is there any reasonable explanation why this snippet is not working in Grails 2.5.0 (Groovy 2.4.3)? It seems that the delegate of the closure is somehow ignored and method lookup is done in Main class scope not the delegate itself.

Changing `trait` into `class` and implementation of a trait into inheritance makes this code working again.

Comment: Pasting that code into the Groovy console for Groovy 2.4.4 works fine

Comment: Right, that's [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7456) in groovy 2.4.3 (which is fixed in 2.4.4)...  THink you're going to need a workaround until a Grails update ups the Groovy version

Comment: I can confirm that. Migrating to Grails 2.5.1 resolves problem as it uses Groovy 2.4.4 where it works as you said.

Comment: @tim_yates you should post that as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it's this bug

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7456

Which is fixed in groovy 2.4.4, so an upgrade of grails should fix it :-)